Continous function with infinitely many zeroes
Let's say I have a function $f(x)$, that is continous everywhere on the real line. Suppose I have a sequence of real numbers $a_k$ such that $a_0$ = $C$ and as $k$ tends to infinity, $a_k$ tends to a real finite number $L$. Thus $a_k$ is Cauchy, and around $L$ the sequence would get arbitrarily close. Now, if $f(a_k)=0$ for all $k$, does it follow that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$? I've tried thinking of counter examples, and one that came to mind was $sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ around $x=0$. However at that point that function is no longer continous, so would it follow then that a function that satisfies those conditions is $0$ everywhere, and how do I prove such a statement?

Multiply your function by $x$ then it continuous.

Consider the function $f(x)$ which is $\exp (-1/x^2)$ for $x>0$ and $0$ if $x≤0$.  That function is infinitely differentiable.  If you don't care about derivatives, you can just take $f(x)=x$ for $x>0$.

By Heine definition of continuity $x_n \to x \Rightarrow f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Proper spelling is continuous
